# Connecting to SQL Database From Azure Linux Web App

Tags: sql, linux, azure, asp.net-core

I'm making a ASP.NET Core web app, and on Azure, due to the fact that web apps running on Linux servers have a significantly lower price than ones running on Windows servers, I would like to run my web app on a Linux server.

The web app makes several calls to a SQL database not on Azure, but somewhere else, and I've added the database connection string in the configurations of the the web app in Azure. I've also added the web app's ip to the list of allowed ip addresses of my SQL database.

However, I can't seem to connect to the database on a web app running on a Linux server. If I make a web app running on a Windows server it works just fine.

Am I perhaps missing something, or is it just not possible to have a SQL database connection from a web app running on a Linux server?

Comment: can you share the error description?

Comment: is there any way you can configure a test app linux server, and deploy the app, with the server details bundled with the deployment code. Instead of making it pick up from Web App Configuration. If this gets your app working, then, you can focus your energies on the app settings. right now, it hard to say if this is a linux related issue or a app setting issue.

Comment: That is a good point! I tried adding the connection string to the appsettings.json file, but it is till not working - so I guess there might be an issue with the SQL database, or the code?

Comment: @Dedoj did you solve it now?